# jquery how to remove both the <tr> tag on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `checkbox` which has `id` - when I select the `checkbox`-es and click the `button`, the `tr` tag should get removed; when I select the multiple `checkbox`-es both `tr` tag should get removed, but the thing is when I select the multiple `checkbox`-es only the `tr` tag belong to the 1st `id` get removed.

I have tried the following code

**jQuery**

```
<script>
    function getsample(val) {
        $(function () {
            checkboxid = $('input[name="chk"]:checked').map(function () {
                return this.id
            }).get();
        });
        $("#" + checkboxid).closest('tr').remove();
    }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>UserName</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Semester</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>student15</td>
                <td>Student</td>
                <td>CS</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>arung@gmail.com</td>
                <td><input name="chk" type="checkbox" id="sam1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>student16</td>
                <td>Student</td>
                <td>CS</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>arung@gmail.com</td>
                <td><input name="chk" type="checkbox" id="sam2"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="button" onclick="getsample()" id="button" value="Submit">
</body>
</html>
```

When I use  `$("#"+this.id).closest('tr').remove();` inside the map function all the selected `tr` tag get removed, but I need to call `checkbox` `id` outside the map function.

Help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `getsample()` function to following.

```js
function getsample(val) {
    $('input[name="chk"]:checked').closest('tr').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>UserName</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Semester</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>student15</td>
            <td>Student</td>
            <td>CS</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>arung@gmail.com</td>
            <td><input name="chk" type="checkbox" id="sam1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>student16</td>
            <td>Student</td>
            <td>CS</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>arung@gmail.com</td>
            <td><input name="chk" type="checkbox" id="sam2"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" onclick="getsample()" id="button" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly loop through the checked check boxes, and remove the parent tr using `$(this).closest("tr")`

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("[name='chk']:checked").each(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/206/)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all `<tr>` tags by using jquery to select all the input fields starting with the id "sam" (or name equal to or starting with "chk") which are checked. This can be done with `$('[id^="sam"]:checked')` where 'id^' stands for "id starting with". You can also remove the '^' for exact match or put 'name' instead of id.

Are working plunker can be found [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/s1ZIG00CkAclrjwkSgx2?p=preview) .